# Monitoring HP MSA2324sa using OpenNMS

Tags: monitoring, storage, system-monitoring, opennms

I was able to get an HP MSA2324sa storage array connected to a server after someone's advice on here to scan the SCSI bus. Now, I want to monitor the following on the storage using SNMP and OpenNMS:

a) the health of the drives
b) the PSU state

However, I'm having a hard time making it work. SNMP is configured on the storage array but when I scan the node, I still don't get any information regarding the disks and the PSU. Should this be published automatically or should I manually add something in OpenNMS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't be able to get much in the way of performance or health information about an MSA storage array over SNMP... Use email alerts and just rely on those.

OpenNMS will be useless here.

Comment: Thanks @ewwhite - is there any other solution you'd recommend? I am currently trying to make some nagios plugins work but am open to any other solutions.

Comment: I would only recommend email alerts on the MSA2000 and P2000 devices. These devices aren't very good for performance monitoring, but they'll at least tell you when an array fails.